# How to do not deploy lambda if no changes on code

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

AWS Lambda are deployed even if there is no change on code and serverless configuration. I would like to do not deploy it...

My code is redeployed even after 2 consecutive `serverless deploy`

I tried to launch, on the same code base, `serverless package` twice and the only the difference is on the `S3Key` and `artifactDirectoryName`.

The resulting serverless-states.json files contain the following S3Key:

```
serverless/[...]/1560423171166-2019-06-13T10:52:51.166Z
serverless/[...]/1560423200593-2019-06-13T10:53:20.593Z
```

So I'd like to understand if this can cause deployment ?
Or is this a bad behavior of serverless ?

```
serverless --version
1.45.1
```

Actually, I'm expecting to do not deploy my lambdas